# Im trying to python libraries , for example PyQt5 and it is showing error as " HTTP 000 connection failed for url "

Tags: python, ssl, installation, pyqt5, conda

When i try to install pyqt5 using conda install it is showing "HTTP 000 connection failed for url". Then i tried pip install it is showing "could not find  a version that satisfies the requirement PyQt5","No matching distribution found for PyQt5". Also some sort of SSL certificate error.

Solutions i tired:
I tried changing the SSl certificate in .condaarc file. **failure**.

I tried downloading the tar file and install directly. im only able to download .tar.bz2 file not .tar.gz file. I didnt get any support page for installing.

Can anyone tell the reason for this kind of error and how to install libraries if this error occurs.

Comment: What pip command did you try?

Comment: I used this command "pip install PyQt5"